# Get value from the select statement on the row above in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the value the previous select statement returned (similar to the `@@IDENTITY` function)

Code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT MyCriticalValue
           FROM Units u
           JOIN pUnit pu
             ON pu.UnitID = u.UnitID
           WHERE u.ChildUnitID = ( SELECT ps.UnitID
                                   FROM psUnit ps
                                   WHERE ps.Code = @CurrentCode)
            AND pu.Type = 117
            AND u.TypeID = 1 )
BEGIN
  SET @CriticalValue = @@identity
END
```

I know that `@@IDENTITY` doesn't work since that's only for inserts. Is there a similar function to achieve what I want (which is to get "MyCriticalValue" from the select statement into the variable `@CriticalValue` without typing the entire SELECT statement twice).

**EDIT:**

Clarification: When I come to this point in my SQL script `@CriticalValue` is already set and I should ONLY overwrite it if the select-statement returns anything, so it should not be overwritten in any other case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @CriticalValue = ISNULL(MyCriticalValue, @CriticalValue)
FROM Units u
JOIN pUnit pu
 ON pu.UnitID = u.UnitID
WHERE u.ChildUnitID = (
                        SELECT ps.UnitID
                        FROM psUnit ps
                        WHERE ps.Code = @CurrentCode
                      )
  AND pu.Type = 117
  AND u.TypeID = 1;

IF @CriticalValue IS NOT NULL
...
```

I assumed that your query return one value.

Comment: Definately valid but @CriticalValue contains a value when I get to this point in the TSQL script that I should NOT overwrite if this new value doesn't exist. Yes, my query returns only 1 value in my DB.
I could of course create a temporary variable but I don't like that either. I would so very much like to get the value in the previous select statement. It would be the nicest solution.

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung See updated answer, Added ISNULL you can use also COALESCE

Comment: Super beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: `select @x = y...` will not set `@x` to any value, unless at least one row is returned. So the `isnulll` in this case has no affect unless `MyCriticalValue` is null. If one wants `@CriticalValue` set to `MyCriticalValue` even when `MyCriticalValue` is null, the `isnull` needs to be removed.